# Compare dates in PHP issue

Tags: php, date

I have an array in PHP that has dates in the following format d/m/yyyy like that:

```
["01/02/2014","02/02/2014","03/02/2014","04/02/2014","05/02/2014","06/02/2014","07/02/2014","08/02/2014","09/02/2014","10/02/2014"]
```

is there a way to do a calculations on date and print only dates that are after `"03/02/2014"` and before `"08/02/2014"` those dates :

```
"04/02/2014","05/02/2014","06/02/2014","07/02/2014"
```

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the most correct answer is "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

```
$dates = ["01/02/2014","02/02/2014","03/02/2014","04/02/2014","05/02/2014","06/02/2014","07/02/2014","08/02/2014","09/02/2014","10/02/2014"];

$first = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", '03/02/2014');
$last  = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", '08/02/2014');
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    if ($date > $first && $date < $last) {
        // you're good
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we editted at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this:

```
$dates = ["01/02/2014","02/02/2014","03/02/2014","04/02/2014","05/02/2014","06/02/2014","07/02/2014","08/02/2014","09/02/2014","10/02/2014"];

$min = new DateTime('2014-03-02');
$max = new DateTime('2014-08-02');

$dates = array_filter($dates, function ($date) use ($min, $max) {
    $dt = new DateTime($date);

    return $dt >= $min && $dt <= $max;
});
```

Comment: Please I have PHP version 5.2.17 and sounds like DateTime is not working

Comment: @OussamaLord `DateTime` was introduced in PHP 5.2 according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` function. Something like

```
<?php

$arr = [
  "01/02/2014",
  "02/02/2014",
  "03/02/2014",
  "04/02/2014",
  "05/02/2014",
  "06/02/2014",
  "07/02/2014",
  "08/02/2014",
  "09/02/2014",
  "10/02/2014"
];

$cmp = strtotime("08/02/2014");

$arr = array_filter($arr, function ($date) use ($cmp) {
  return strtotime($date) < $cmp;
});

print_r($arr);
```

### References

- http://php.net/array_filter
- http://php.net/strtotime